# Flutter: can a StatelessWidget return a StatefulWidget from its build method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am wondering what will happen if I define a StatelessWidget but return a stateful Widget from its build method? I've tried it and everything seems to be working, but I just want to know what is going on behind the scene so that I can be sure nothing will break when I ship it into production. Specifically:

1) I am wondering if every rebuild of the parent StatelessWidget will trigger a rebuild of the StatefulWidget it returns? If so, is it saying I am effectively returning a StatelessWidget?

2) I am wondering if the parent StatelessWidget will still be in the widget tree, given it is merely a wrapper and does not have any visual element to be rendered?

3) If I want to give the child StatefulWidget a Key, should I give the parent StatelessWidget the same key? Or, should I just put the key on the parent StatelessWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing Stateless and Stateful is a very, very, *very* common use-case.

The answer is relatively simple: Nothing special happens.

Stateless+Stateful is the same as Stateless*2 or Stateful*2. There's no behavior change and no extra code needed.

> I am wondering if every rebuild of the parent StatelessWidget will trigger a rebuild of the StatefulWidget it returns? If so, is it saying I am effectively returning a StatelessWidget?

No. Each widget is independent and can rebuild without forcing other widgets to rebuild.

A child rebuilding won't make the parent rebuild. Similarly, a parent rebuilding doesn't necessarily force the child to rebuild either.

> I am wondering if the parent StatelessWidget will still be in the widget tree, given it is merely a wrapper and does not have any visual element to be rendered?

Yes, a StatelessWidget is still in the tree.

No, it is not "just a wrapper." A StatelessWidget can use InheritedWidgets and override `==`.

These can cause the widget to rebuild independently from other widgets. And as such, this widget must say in the tree.

It even has a `setState` equivalent; it's just not public.

> If I want to give the child StatefulWidget a Key, should I give the parent StatelessWidget the same key? Or, should I just put the key on the parent StatelessWidget?

No. That's not needed.

If the key is on a widget, this will impact its entire subtree. So there's no need to put it on descendants too.

In fact, you can't, depending on the Key. GlobalKey, for example, requires to be unique.